# Ubuntu on Asus X205TA

Tags: usb, uefi, asus

I want to install Ubuntu on my new netbook Asus X205TA. I try to create a USB stick with Unebootin but not succes for boot on.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you "enable CSM" boot in BIOS?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working.  I got my X205TA 4 days ago and finally had time to set it up.  Here are the instructions to install 14.10:

https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It helps, but not all the way :-) Your link says "cp /tmp/bootia32.efi /mnt/EFI/BOOT/" There was no /mnt/EFI, so I mkdir'ed /mnt/EFI/BOOT and followed along. I *did* get the ASUS to boot off of the USB (Huzzah!) but only into a grub2 prompt. So, I'm not able to "Install Ubuntu as usual." A bit more detail about how to proceed would be useful. Thanks for the help so far, though!

Comment: The absence of /mnt/EFI/BOOT was my fault; I was using a 32-bit iso, not the 64-bit. Sorry for the noise. But, with that resolved, I still cannot install ubuntu as normal. When booting off of the usb, I am dropped into a grub rescue prompt. I don't know how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

I got Ubuntu to boot without much effort.

1. Make a bootable usb stick of **Ubuntu 14.10**. Use Rufus(Windows) or Startup Disk Creator(Ubuntu).
2. Copy [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56Bn2CVqCWFMkRmQnZsUUE2dlE/view?usp=sharing) (bootia32.efi) to **/EFI/BOOT** directory on the usb stick.
3. Turn *Secure Boot* off in the BIOS.
4. Boot from the usb stick.

This should boot Ubuntu 14.10 without any other issues. For further info [check this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610456/ubuntu-on-asus-eeebookx205-with-all-peripherals/611708#611708) on askubuntu.

Comment: you did this with the Asus X205TA?

Comment: I tried many things in order to boot froom a usb drive on the Asus X205TA and nothing worked. Finally, adding the file to the /EFI/BOOT directory worked.