# Trying to install Ubuntu on ASUS X205TA

Tags: system-installation, asus

I want to install Ubuntu on the Asus X205TA. 
https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/

I created a successful USB Installer (I've tested it on other computers) however I cant seem to get the computer to Boot from USB even manually from BIOS.

I've found the following link but am having trouble following the steps. It opens with "On a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.10 system". But I can't get the installer to even be recognized. 
https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md

Thank you.

Comment: The instructions you link to could be a bit clearer (and I've not been able to get them to work all the way through). The suggestion is to prepare the USB key from which you want to install onto the x205TA on another machine which has an installation of ubuntu 14.10; the tools used aren't available on Windows. This would have been better posted as a comment on the answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/551320/ubuntu-on-asus-x205ta.

Answer (score 2):

My Asus x200 will not boot when secure boot is enabled, but works just fine when secure boot is disabled.  UEFI mode otherwise works fine.  The other 'gotcha' is that the boot order is not persistent when the usb is removed.  The default order of hard disk first is reset, so you might have to play around with that too.

---

My BIOS is American Megatrends version 203, GOP version 3.0.1023, EC version B14E150001
Don't know anything about bitlocker.
To be more clear:  The specific USB needs to be plugged in as the UEFI settings are run and the bootorder changed to put it first.  The USB item in the boot order list is pretty specific to the USB, including brand and type.  Any boot without that specific USB will remove it from the bootorder.

Comment: May I know if you had to turn bitlocker off before that? I had my bitlocker on, but when I disabled SecureBoot, I didn't see the USB but windows wanted my bitlocker recovery key before letting me in. Post that, It did let me in to my computer but I still cannot see my USB drivee in the boot menu. My BIOS version is 205 (latest being 208).

Answer (score 0):

Debian latest ISOs are working for this laptop now. Try

http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/multi-arch/iso-cd/