# X205TA Ubuntu 15.04 Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 15.04

Netbook ASUS X205TA Windows 8.1 Single language with Bing, 64GBeMMC Samsung, 32GB Samsung EVO MicroSDHC Class 10 UHS-1, 8GB Sandisk USB 2.0.

I've been able to Try Ubuntu from USB Flash Disk, create 20GB logical ext4 + 500MB swap partition. I go to Ubuntu 15.04 Install, the problem when Install are: 
Unable to Install GRUB in /dev/mmcblk0
Executing 'grub-install /dev/mmcblk0'failed. 
This is fatal error.

Please help me how to do with this, I'm new for computing.
Thanks for advance

Comment: google `x205ta linux install` it's all over the internet

Answer (score 0):

Refer [stackoverflow question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554418/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-x205ta), [Instructions to install Ubuntu 14.10 on ASUS EeeBook X205TA](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md). This may help you.

Comment: The difference between that's guide are mine 64GB eMMC, don't have USB wifi adapter, can't decrypt since win8.1 SL bing doesn't have option to turn off/disable bitlocker. I can boot from grub 2, choose try ubuntu/install ubuntu but failed execute grub /dev/mmcblk0 when install n

Answer (score 0):

Using the regular install wizard:

When the options titled "Installation Type" comes you are given a choice between:

- Erase disk and install Xubuntu
- Something else

[image: Installation Type Screenshot]

Choose: **Something else**

At the bottom is a pulldown menu titled **Device for boot loader installation**, select `/dev/sda`

[image: Installation Type Partition Screenshot]

Now click on the **Back** and proceed with **Erase disk and install Xubuntu**

This should solve this issue.