# Is Intel Atom z3735 supported?

Tags: server, ubuntu-touch, hardware

I have a tablet PC whose central processor is Intel Atom z3735g@1.33ghz, with Windows 8. The system is damaged and doesn't work so I want to install Ubuntu.

Is there an Ubuntu Touch, desktop Ubuntu, Ubuntu Server or some other Ubuntu that has support for this processor?

Comment: Boot from live USB stick, and test to see if everything works. If it does, you can install. If not, you don't have to.

Comment: Here's a prediction: This "Bay Trail" based tablet will boot to a live session and you let you install - the 32-bit UEFI roadblock has been overcome - but many devices won't work, among them audio and WiFi. The level of expertise required to fix that is higher then most advanced Linux users. So, at the end of day, a good project but impractical for a daily drive. It hurts me to say this but... Recover and keep the preinstalled Windows only.

Comment: See http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-install-ubuntu-onto-a-windows-tablet-1319489

Comment: I have the same processor (and 100% Ubuntu) see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail) for the workaround for one very annoying issue.

Answer (score 3):

Man, you've got a unfortunate SoC, that is Bay Trail. I'll just quote the relevant part of [another answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/815688/266507) on the like matter:

> There's a bigger problem: you've got a System-On-Chip called Bay Trail, and Intel is struggling yet to supply good support *(which is funny, given the number of engineers, and that Bay Trail is in production)*. Most of the issues are fixed as of kernel 4.7, except that there's no sound.
>
> You can track [the process of solving the bug with sound here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86581). I'd recommend to hold with installation, while it gets solved *(or, just in case you're a programmer, you could try to join the fun of getting the sound up and running)*.

Comment: +1 Because it is a good explanation of the problem. I do not know why somebody downvoted this (and did not add an explanation so the user could enhance his answer).