# Error message during boot after installing tlp

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, tlp

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 via [linuxium](http://www.linuxium.com.au/) in my Lenovo Ideapad 100s, then wiped out Ubuntu Desktop and installed Ubuntu Server using tasksel. And after installing tlp, I get the messages

```
axp288_fuel_gauge: ADC charge current read failed
```

and

```
thinkpad_acpi: Not yet supported Thinkpad detected!
```

when I boot. The messages don't appear when I remove tlp.  Is there way to solve this problem or at least hide those messages?

---

After I tried from same environment after reinstalling Ubuntu, 
`axp288_fuel_gauge: ADC charge current read failed` does not appear but `thinkpad_acpi: Not yet supported Thinkpad detected!` still appears. The same message appears when I start tlp.

Comment: Two questions for clarification:  Did you install 'tlp' frum the Ubuntu repositories, or the linrunner PPA?  And did you also install 'tp-smapi-dkms'?

Comment: @Charles Green I installed from ubuntu repositories. I didn't installed what you asked manually but I can find it from apt list and when I type ' apt install tp-smapi-dkms' apt shows several packages that i can install

Comment: The question has been closed which prevents me from writing an answer; however the [TLP documentation](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) indicates that for a thinkpad, either `tp-smapi-dkms` or `acpi-call-dkms` is required for thinkpads - both should be installed, and if unneeded, they will not be active.  Please try `sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms` and see if the error recurs.

Comment: The question was probably closed because of unclarity - what is linuxium, why are you using it, and why didn't you simply download a server installation from [ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)?

Comment: @Charles Green linuxium is script that allow intel atom pcs to boot linux(I read that they need 32bit bootloader to boot 64bit OS so can't boot in usual way I dont know what it technically means) and it includes some useful settings for atom(like wifi audio firmware...). The script doesn't support server one so I installed desktop and wiped out desktop. My laptop is actually ideapad one(not thinkpad) so I cant understand why thinkpad error appears. I'm installing ubuntu again and I'll try your advice thanks!

Comment: In case it doesnt work do you know how to hide those messages?

Comment: No, although you could try to comment on some of the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815301/can-ubuntu-be-installed-on-an-ideapad-100s-atom-laptop) - a couple of people had reported varying levels of success getting the ideapad to operate

Answer (score 0):

The message "thinkpad_acpi: Not yet supported Thinkpad detected!" is triggered by TLP. To check whether it's running on a ThinkPad it tries to load  thinkpad_acpi kernel module.

But the real cause is the kernel module thinkpad_acpi itself, which confuses your Ideapad with an unknown ThinkPad model.

Solution: either ignore the message or file a bug report against the kernel.

Remark: don't confuse thinkpad_acpi – part of the standard kernel – with tp-smapi – additional dkms package needed – or acpi-call. Neither tp-smapi nor acpi-call a related to the error. TLP tries them only after thinkpad_acpi was successfully loaded.