# How do I get my Lenovo 100S to boot from USB?

Tags: uefi, 32-bit, grub-efi, ideapad

I cannot get my Lenovo 100S ideapad to boot from my Ubuntu 18 LTS bootable USB. The laptop currently has Windows 10 32 bit on it. After disabling secure boot in the EFI BIOS so that I could change the boot order, Windows BitLocker has kicked in and locked the drive. Every time the computer boots now, it enters BitLocker drive recovery.

```
DEVICE SPECIFICATIONS=
Product Name: Lenovo ideapad 100S-11IBY
BIOS Version: E2CN13WW
EC Version: E2EC12WW
Lenovo SN: YD00S4Y4
CPU: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU Z3735F @ 1.33GHz
System Memory: 2048 MB
Storage: SanDisk DB4032
Preinstalled OS license SDK0J91117 WIN
OA3 Key ID 3259182586809
```

If I try to boot up the computer normally, it will first enter BitLocker drive recovery. I hit the "Skip this drive" button to proceed (because I don't care to get Windows back on the computer). Then it gives me the following options:

- Continue: This just leads to the BitLocker menu again.
- Use a device: This allows me "EFI USB Device", "EFI DVD/CDROM" (which I don't have), and "EFI Network" (which I don't have set up). If I choose "EFI USB Device" (with the Ubuntu 18 installation media plugged in) I get *"System doesn't have any USB boot option. Please select other boot option in Boot Manager Menu."*

If I press the 'Novo' button then <kbd>F1</kbd> key, I get a menu that says "Boot Option Menu" then "EFI Boot Devices" and then "Windows Boot Manager" is selected with a grey highlight. Underneath that it says [up] and [down] to change option, ENTER to select an option, ESC to exit" but it does not change the selection when I press up or down.

When I do get in to the BIOS using the ['Novo' button](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-enter-boot-menu-in-Lenovo) then F1 key, it shows me the "Information" I posted above under DEVICE SPECIFICATIONS, my "Configuration" options include "Secure Boot" (which I have off), "Reset to Setup Mode", and "BIOS Back Flash" (which is off). There are other options, but I don't believe they would be relevant to my problem here.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Linux-on-Ideapad-100s-11IBY/td-p/3367825 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/815301/can-ubuntu-be-installed-on-intel-atom-based-laptop-or-mini-pc (Google was my friend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out these computers require a hybrid of 64 and 32 bit images.

I found [these instructions](https://medium.com/@realzedgoat/a-sorta-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-linux-on-32-bit-uefi-machines-d39b1d1961ec) to be most helpful.

I was having trouble creating the bootable USB with Ubuntu, because it gave me a permissions error when I tried to replace the 64 bit boot loader with a 32 bit one. Rufus on Windows 10 did this just fine.

I was also having issues seeing any option to boot from USB in the EUFI BIOS. I solved this by following the steps below (copied from the linked article) exactly.

1. Turn off the machine
2. Press the recovery button next to the HDD light.
3. Select BIOS Setup
4. In configuration, turn off Secure boot, select Reset to Setup Mode.
5. Press F10 to save and exit.
6. Turn off the machine again, press the recovery button.
7. Select Boot Menu
8. Select Ubuntu under EFI Boot Devices.