# add files to iso under ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, filesystem, 16.10, iso

I need to add a file to the lubuntu iso in order to boot from a 64 bit iso as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551320/ubuntu-on-asus-x205ta)

I tried to do it as explained [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1334533) and nothing happens

I tried to mount it like explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write) and get the following error:

> desktop-amd64.iso /media/iso
>   mount: /media/iso not mounted or bad option

```
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

And i also try to mount it with Furius iso and when i try to copy something to the mounted folder, it raises the error

> Error while creating directory Untitled Folder.
>   There was an error creating the directory in /home/shai/lubuntu-16_10-desktop-amd64_iso.
>   Error creating directory: Function not implemented

Is there any straight forward way to add a file to the iso?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to add? (i'm just curious)

Comment: added an update of what i try to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to add the file using isomaster 
i installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install isomaster
```